# definition of generic function

Tags: reference-request, at.algebraic-topology, differential-topology, riemann-surfaces, mapping-class-groups

what is definition of **generic function** in following [paper](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwjBqNSai_30AhWpRPEDHeGeDGYQFnoECAgQAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fpi.math.cornell.edu%2F%7Ehatcher%2FPapers%2FMCGpresentation.pdf&usg=AOvVaw113eSaaQ0fOElNR-jKX5eQ) ? i need a reference for definition  generic function .

"A. Hatcher, W. Thurston, A presentation for the mapping class group of a closed orientable surface "

...let f be any **generic function** on M having $C_1, . . . , C_r$ as non-critical level curves....

Comment: This was already posted on Math StackExchange [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4341344). It is considered rude on these sites to cross-post without pointing out the other post, as it could lead to duplication of effort. KReiser's comment on the MSE post is correct. One often says that an element of some particular comeagre set of functions is 'a generic function'. Hatcher and Thurston are looking at the space of smooth functions for which C_1, ..., C_g are non-critical level curves, and "generic" means whatever it needs for the argument to work; I'd need to read the paper to say more.

Comment: @‍KReiser's [comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4341344/what-is-definition-of-generic-function#comment9056175_4341344) [referenced](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/412472/definition-of-generic-function#comment1056980_412472) by @mme.

Comment: For a topological space X, "a generic element of X" means: "an element of a second category subset of X".